# el.click() produces strange Selenium Webdriver Error

Tags: node.js, selenium, suman

I have this block of code:

```
 it('tests cookies', opts, async t => {
    await driver.get(`${cdthost}/#!/my-acquisitions/${acqId}`).then(function () {
      return Promise.delay(3000);
    });
    await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id(`acq-dropdown-item-${acqId}`)), 4000).then(function () {
      console.log(`acq-dropdown-item-${acqId} has been located.`);
    });
    let el = await driver.findElement(By.id(`acq-dropdown-item-${acqId}`));
    console.log('el => ', el);
    await el.click().then(() => Promise.delay(2000)).catch(function (e) {
      console.error(' => Trapped click() error => ', e.stack || e);
    });
    return driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function (val) {
      assert(val === `${cdthost}/#!/my-acquisitions/${acqId}`, 'We have a hella fast runner.');
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.error(' => Trapped getCurrentUrl() error => ', err.stack || err);
    })

  });
```

I am getting **the following error** from the above routine:

```
 => Trapped click() error =>  WebDriverError: 
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'c8c5331543cc', ip: '172.18.0.3', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.9.27-moby', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{moz:profile=/tmp/rust_mozprofile.usqz3L7o9x89, rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0.0, pageLoad=300000.0, script=30000.0}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, platform=ANY, specificationLevel=0.0, moz:accessibilityChecks=false, acceptInsecureCerts=false, browserVersion=53.0, platformVersion=4.9.27-moby, moz:processID=445.0, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=linux}]
Session ID: 959d0cca-24a2-4335-b6d3-a60c635cbf36
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/usr/local/cdt-tests/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:517:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/usr/local/cdt-tests/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (/usr/local/cdt-tests/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

does anyone know why click() would produce such an error? What does it mean? How can I fix?

When I log the `el`, I get this:

```
el =>  WebElement {
  driver_: 
   thenableWebDriverProxy {
     flow_: SimpleScheduler {},
     session_: PatchedPromise { [Object] },
     executor_: Executor { w3c: false, customCommands_: [Object], log_: [Object] },
     fileDetector_: null,
     onQuit_: [Function: onQuit],
     cancel: [Function],
     then: [Function: bound ],
     catch: [Function: bound ] },
  id_: PatchedPromise { '4' } }
```

Comment: Is the `val === `${cdthost}/#!/my-acquisitions/${acqId}`` truthy ?

Comment: I will check, but I don't see how that could cause a "WebDriverError"

Comment: I updated the code to use async/await, but the problem is the same

Comment: Can you locate at which point is the error thrown ? After the .click(); ?

Comment: not sure, let me check  - my guess is that I didn't explicitly provide the capability to add cookies? It does say: "WebDriverError: Capabilities "

Comment: Yeah it's the click() that causes the error, I checked... (async/await does not propagate errors the same way as pure promises, kind of bad). I updated the question to reflect all of this..thanks.